# How to format a string for URL in php

Tags: php, regex

I am creating routes for my project. For that purpose, I have to format some string. I already did that by the following code,

```
//Removing unwanted characters
$output = preg_replace( '/[+()^ $%&*~]/', '-', 'This is% my $junk68++ds)(-67url' );

//Removing duplicated dashes
$output = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $output);

//Removing dashesat the end
if(substr($output,-1)=="-"){
echo substr($output,0,-1);
}else{
echo $output;
};
```

It works but I hope there is a better way to do that. Could anybody here help me, please?

Comment: Use `preg_replace( '/[+()^ $%&*~]+/', '-', 'This is% my $junk68++ds)(-67url' )`

Comment: Instead of using a blacklist, I would turn it around and use a white-list. `[^\w-]` would be a good start. And you can remove trailing `-` characters easily using `rtrim()`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your response. but the output is This-is-my-junk68-ds--67url and it's not correct. I am expecting an output without duplicate dashes like - This-is-my-junk68-ds-67url

Comment: Add `-` to the  pattern and a `+` quantifier: `preg_replace( '/[-+()^ $%&*~]+/', '-', 'This is% my $junk68++ds)(-67url' )`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's working.. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-` to the pattern and a `+` quantifier to the character class, and then remove leading/trailing hyphens with [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

```
trim(preg_replace( '/[-+()^ $%&*~]+/', '-', 'This is% my $junk68++ds)(-67url' ), '-')
                      ^           ^
```

When the hyphen is added at the start/end of the character class it does not have to be escaped.

The `+` quantifier will match whole chunks of consecutive chars matched with the character class.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Lt1uk9/2) and a [**live PHP demo**](https://3v4l.org/QFjP3).

```
echo trim( 
    preg_replace( '/[-+()^ $%&*~]+/', '-', '--This is% my $junk68++ds)(-67url-%-' ),
    '-'
);
// => This-is-my-junk68-ds-67url
```